# java xml xslt transformation issue with big xsl files

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I use the below code to filter an xml using xslt.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XMLTransformation {
private static String TASK = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            TASK = args[0];
            System.out.println("TASK being filtered is " + TASK);
        } else {
            System.out.println("TASK NOT supplied..Exiting");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        String TASK_VAR = TASK.replaceAll("\\.", "_");
        String input_file_param = String.valueOf(TASK_VAR) + "_INPUT_FILE";
        String output_file_param = String.valueOf(TASK_VAR) + "_OUTPUT_FILE";
        String xsl_file_param = String.valueOf(TASK_VAR) + "_XSL_FILE";
        StreamSource input = new StreamSource(System.getenv(input_file_param));
        StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(System.getenv(xsl_file_param));
        StreamResult output = new StreamResult(System.getenv(output_file_param));
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        transformer.transform(input, output);
    }
    catch (TransformerException te) {
        System.out.println("Transformer exception: " + te.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

the code works fine for smaller XML files but throws the error **"Transformer exception: Could not load the translet class"** for larger ones.

what is wrong with this code? can someone suggest please?

Comment: For a start, replace `catch (TransformerException te) { System.out.println("Transformer exception: " + te.getMessage());}` with `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and check and post the complete stack trace. If it is a memory problem then give the JRE more memory. And you might want to share what "larger" means in terms of megabytes or gigabytes and which memory you have available to run the transformation. As XSLT works on an in-memory tree representation of the complete input XML processing large files needs enough memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution of course is to try a different processor. You could switch to the Xalan interpreter version by setting the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory to org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl, or to Saxon by setting it to net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.

Frankly, if you're in the Java world, it's hard to see why anyone would want to restrict themselves to an XSLT 1.0 processor these days, especially one that hasn't had any active development for years. Switch to Saxon.

Comment: thanks Michael...This was a legacy code I was trying to fix :)